# There is a crash when I use MimeKit in Xamrain.IOS

Tags: xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms, mimekit

Intalled the Mime Kit and MailKit to packages folder of xamrion.IOS, and try to use them to send an email. It works, but there is a crash when **running new MimeMessage()**
How to fix this issue.
I am a super beginner with IOS AND Xamarin, thanks very much for your help.

About 6 or 7 lines unable to locate assembly 'I18N' (culture:'')

**Log:** 
2017-07-27 16:18:05.103 AAAA.iOS[523:215341] Xamarin.iOS: Unable to locate assembly 'I18N' (culture: '')

```
async public void sentEmail(string fileName, string addressEmail)
    {

        var message = new MimeMessage();
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(" SendMail  MimeMessage ");
```

Comment: You should search if it has been reported, https://github.com/jstedfast/MimeKit/issues and if not, you can create a new issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, if you are using the simulator you will not be able to send emails using anything that depends on Apple's mail app because it is not installed on the simulator.

If that's not the case, i would recommend using UIMessage instead. Xamarin has great documentation on how to create a pop over view to compose an email and send wit from inside your custom application.

**EDIT:**
here is the the link to the [Xamarin tutorial on sending emails](https://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/ios/shared_resources/email/send_an_email/).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Could you please share the Great documentation's link. I can't find it. Thank you.

Comment: Lol for sure. Sorry about that!!

Comment: MFMailComposeViewController, I can not modify  the from email field, It doesn't math my retirement. I need to set our company's official email address as the from email no matter in any devices.

Comment: Sorry there is no way to do that with the UIMessage class nor with MFMailComposeViewController. Additionally, what you are trying to do is spoof email, which is a very delicate process and will most likely result in your emails being caught in spam filters due to SPF failures. The recommended way to send emails from an ios device is to use UIMessage sending from the default mail account on the device. Sorry if that isn't much help. You should be very careful with the spoofing though because even if you spend all this time and get it to work, emails may be blocked by the recipients email servic

Answer (score 0):

You need to go into your iOS Project Options -> iOS Build options and then enable the i18n assemblies to be included.